# Firebase onUpdate triggering at the root node instead of deep path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase Realtime database and I use Cloud functions to trigger certain actions on an update.

Here is my data structure:

```
....: {},
....: {},
routes: {
    '-route_id_123': {
        access_code: 'accessCode1234',
        active: true,
        on_trip: false,
        parents: { 
            ....: true 
        },
        ....: '...',
        ....: '...',
        ....: {}
   }
 },
 ....: {}
```

I've written a cloud function that looks at the following path:

```
exports.someFunction = functions.database.ref('routes/{route_id}/on_trip').onUpdate((change, context) => {....}
```

What's actually happening is that this function is getting triggered at `'routes/'`, the root and not **only** at `.../on_trip`. For example if I set `active` as true or false in the structure above, the function gets triggered while the expectation is that this function will only be triggered when there is a change to the `on_trip` value.

What I noticed is that even if I set the path to `/foo/bar/baz/really/deep/path` the function seems to be triggering at `/foo/`.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Note that I am testing using the firebase emulator for both the database and functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the emulator, file an issue on GitHub with your observations. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I suppose that could be it since this does not make sense. I just updated my firebase-tools and tried again (not sure if it makes any difference) and still face the issue. Let me log it in there.